# Mvc: route config order routes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, routes

i have added a custom route like this

```
        routes.MapRoute(
          name: "Default",
          url: "{coutry}/{lang}/{controller}/{action}",
          defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
        );
```

now im getting some problems when i try to call a method from one controller, this was working good before add the new route

```
<a id="someId" class="link-button" href="../Documents/Create"><span>Create</span></a>
```

now the only way i can achieve that is with something like `href="EN/us/Documents/Create"`

is there a way for keeping the custom route for my client side, and still keeping the `href="../Documents/Create">` way for my admin side, it´s because i have several functionality in admin side developed but now i have to include that custom route for client side. Thank you so much.

There are my routes now

```
 routes.MapRoute(
          name: "Default",
          url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
          defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
      );

routes.MapRoute(
            name: "CustomRoute",
            url: "{country}/{lang}/{controller}/{action}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Test", action = "Index" }
        );
```

but i can only access to CustomRoute with /ES/es/Test/Index ... why is not taking default values ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to declare your custom route **after** the default route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index",
        id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
// SomeOther = someothercontroller
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "CustomRoute",
    url: "{coutry}/{lang}/{controller}/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "SomeOther", action = "Index" }
);
```

Comment: The default route config should be always at the end of the Route config. Since the route config will parse for matching configuration it will accept and route to that path. So if you specify the default configuration at the beginning it will always match and route to that path.

Comment: I know that and that was my first answer, see my edit, but looking closely at his example it's not the case.

Comment: I really aprecciate your help, please review my edit and tell me if you know whats happening ...

Comment: Okay to make sure I did not give you a wrong answer, at least something that works, I tested my own code. So I have that route config I gave you and this: `<a id="someId" class="link-button" href="../Documents/Create"><span>Create</span></a>
<a class="link-button" href="EN/us/someother/testmethod2"><span>Go to Method 2</span></a>`. Both method was called. So what do you mean by `why is not taking default values`?

Comment: Ok you are right so what im trying to tell u is, the CustomRoute is for my index, and when I try to acces with `http://localhost:xxxx/Es/es/` i get 404 error, it is not taken SomeOther controller and Index action as we define in defaults, i can only get acces with `http://localhost:xxxx/Es/es/SomeOther/Index` and i need the firs way please. Thanks.

Comment: @vonv. im going to mark as answer, in fact it was the answer but i  have now this new issue, i would really aprecciate your help with this, and sorry by the other question, i was a litle ashamed with you.

Comment: Just saw your comment on another question. I said no need to be feel ashamed, people are here to help you out, and help each other. And to build a wiki-site with rich content ;)

Comment: @vonv. I ask a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23237336/mvc-route-map-without-any-routing-parameter would you please check it

Answer (score 1):

You have replaced the default RouteConfig to the new configuration and it does match a Url in this **{coutry}/{lang}/{controller}/{action}** format.

If you want to accept the `../Documents/Create` Url You have to add the default RouteConfig at the end.

```
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "CustomRoute",
  url: "{coutry}/{lang}/{controller}/{action}",
  defaults: new { controller = "Documents", action = "Index" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
  name: "Default",
  url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
  defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Also in the anchor tag `<a id="someId" class="link-button" href="../Documents/Create"><span>Create</span></a>` instead of hardcoding the `href` you can write the like following.

`<a id="someId" class="link-button" href="@Url.Action("Create","Documents")><span>Create</span></a>`

Comment: Thanks for your help it´s stil not working for me, please review my edit and tell me if you know what´s happening ?

Comment: @Steve : Updated my answer and please try.

Comment: you are right and I tried your answer, thank you so much, but now im getting the problem that i can only access to CustomRoute with /ES/es/Test/Index, it is for home page and i need acces it with /Es/es only, some ideas ?

Comment: What is your default `Controller` and `action` name? Where should it be redirected when a request comes with `/Es/es` Url?

Comment: this is now `routes.MapRoute(
            name: "CustomRoute",
            url: "{country}/{lang}/{controller}/{action}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Test", action = "Index" }
        );` with Test controller and Index action, but Im still getting 404 error when `/Es/es Url`